# Configure Apache2 to automatically append default file extention to a URL when one is not given

Tags: apache, config

How do I configure Apache2 to load a page with the extensions of default files provided when a page is requested without an extension.

So for example I want http://webpage.com/page to automatically load either:

- http://webpage.com/page.html OR
- http://webpage.com/page.php

NOTE: I don't want any redirection or URL renaming to occur; meaning I want the address bar to still be showing http://webpage.com/page

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

Answer (score 1):

Per [CBroe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) comments and his reference to apache docs [httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews) - Adding **Multiviews** to Options directive inside a Directory section solves this issue.

You can either add it to a Directory section like below (to affect all web applications under sites directory)

```
<Directory /sites>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

-OR- inside a site host definition

```
<VirtualHost *:80> #site.dev
    ServerAdmin admin@email.com
    ServerName site.dev
    ServerAlias site.dev
    DocumentRoot /sites/site.dev

    <Directory /sites/site.dev>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```